# How to pre-determine the names of the generated Python files from the antlr4 tool command line switches?

Tags: python, antlr4

I am using Antlr version 4.11, if that matters, and I am using Python3. Right now I have a combined lexer and parser grammar specification with "default" command line options. I can easily see that my grammar named `Utt` generates the following Python files:

- `UttLexer.py`
- `UttParser.py` and
- `UttListener.py`.

Now, I am interested in learning about the general case to be able to create a generic build rule for the Antlr-Python combination.

Comment: Those names should not change regardless of the options used in the Antlr tool call. However, you should never assume anything. The names are given by using the `-depend` option on the command line. If you are writing build rules, your "clean" step should remove all the files mentioned. (Note, it doesn't list all generated files though.)

Comment: @BartKiers: I am currently tinkering with https://github.com/GorNishanov/rules_antlr, but that is not closely related to the question.

Comment: Nvm, Kaby understood the question :)